# Getting all of foreign key's fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models. One model is the User model, another is a Post model, and the other is a notifications model. I want to use Django's REST framework to show all of the notifications for the signed in user, plus each user that interacted with the signed in user.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='actors')
    actor       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users') 
    post        = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    type        = models.ForeignKey(NotifType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_read     = models.BooleanField()
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    share_count     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url             = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class GetNotifications(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.request.user.id)
        return User.objects.select_related().filter(users__user=user).order_by("-users__created_at")
```

What I have currently returns all users who have interacted with the signed in user. However, it doesn't return the details about the notification. I want all details about each notification, including the details about the post. So the output should be something like this:

```
{
  "post": {
     "id": 1,
     "status": "Hello!",
      .
      .
      .
   },
   "user": {
      "username": "Ben",
      "avatar": "example.png"
      .
      .
   },
   is_read: 1,
   created_at: 2017-07-21,
   type: 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your view as:

```
class GetNotifications(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        ## user = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.request.user.id)
        ## i believe the above line is redundant, you can use self.request.user to access the loged-in user
        return Notification.objects.select_related().filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("created_at")
```

then change your notification serializer as:

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notification

        exclude = ('user',)
        depth = 1
```

or you can define new serializer for actor and post and use it like this:

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    actor = ActorSerializer()
    post = PostSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Notification

        exclude = ('user',)
```

Comment: Since the requested user is a single persion, the **`order_by("-users__created_at")`** statement is *irrelevant* here

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to not show the `user` in the JSON? I only want the `actor.` Is there also a way to not show all fields for `actor`?

Comment: yes you can do the same thing for `ActorSerializer`, specifying fields you want in 'fields' or exclude fields you don't want using 'exclude', take a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Cannot set both 'fields' and 'exclude' options on serializer NotificationSerializer.`

Comment: Yes, this works now. Is there a way to exclude specific fields in actor? Like password?

Comment: just put 'password' in `exclude` in your `ActorSerializer`.(you can not use depth now, you have to write a serializer for Actor)

Comment: I see, which one is more efficient? Exclude or creating separate serializers?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my previous comment, in case that you want to exclude a field from `actor` you have to create a new serializer for Actor and exclude that field in that serializer.

Comment: Sorry, i mean in the event i want all of the fields, which is better using separate serializers or using depth = 1?

Comment: it doesn't really make any difference in efficiency, but I prefer using separate serializer and specifying the fields I want.

Answer (score 1):

You define the serializer for user and posts. Your serializers.py should be

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = PostSerializer()
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Hmm, how would you do the query though?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class NotificationSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notification

        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

        fields = '__all__'

class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = PostSerial(many=True, source='post_set')
    user = NotificationSerial(many=True, source='actors')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```